# :gsub not working as expected in lua script

Tags: string, replace, lua

I am writing a lua script & want to perform an operation like-

```
input_string = "smart app"
output_string = "app"
```

```
input_string = "smart" or input_string = "smart "
output_string = nil (null)
```

I am using the below lua snippet to replace "smart " with empty string so that it solves both the cases.

`output_string = input_string:gsub("smart ", "")`

However I get below responses for each case respectively.

```
input_string = "smart app"
output_string = "app"
```

```
input_string = "smart" or imput_string = "smart "
output_string = "smart"
```

Why does it not work for case 2? Where am I making mistake? Please suggest.

P.s. I do not want to write separate logic to handle both cases, ideally my snippet should solve the case in one line.

UPDATE QUESTION:

in case

> input_string = "smr" or "smr "

I mean any other word, then also I expect `output_string = nil`

You could say that all I want is the second word of the string with exactly one space between first & second word. For anything else, I want a null output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `input_string = "smart" or input_string = "smart "`, `output_string = nil (null)`

This is not possible using `gsub` alone. `gsub` will always produce a string. If you want the empty string `""` to be converted to `nil`, you will have to write extra logic: `if output_string == "" then output_string = nil end`

> `input_string = "smart"` is erroneously converted to `output_string = "smart"`

Your pattern contains a trailing space. For it to match, your input must contain `smart` followed by a space. Just `smart` does not end with a space.

Make the space optional: `smart ?` will greedily try to match a space, but will also accept no space. Caveat: This will also convert `smartass` to `ass`.

Matching end-of-string *or* a space as would be possible in RegEx using `( |$)` is not possible with patterns since alternation (`|`) is not supported.

Alternatively, you can use extra logic by just handling `"smart"` explicitly: `if input_string == "smart" then output_string = "" end`. This will deal properly with `smartass`, keeping it intact.

Note that you might want `%s` instead of a literal space to accept other spacing such as tabs. You'll also probably want a quantifier like `*` to accept multiple space characters. I'd also add the `^` anchor to the beginning of your pattern to not replace `smart` anywhere in the string.

All in all, I'd recommend `output_string = input_string:gsub("^smart%s*", "")`

---

Regarding your update:

> `input_string = "smr" or "smr "`
>
> I mean any other word, then also I expect output_string = nil
> You could say that all I want is the second word of the string with exactly one space between first & second word. For anything else, I want a null output.

In that case, you definitely want `output_string = input_string:match("^smart (.+)")`.

Explanation: This expects your string to start with `smart`  and then greedily captures the remaining characters till the end. If you want to support an empty word if the string is just `"smart "`, use `.*` instead of `.+`.

If the string does not start with `smart` , this won't match and the result will be `nil`.

Comment: pls check the update question once @Luatic